# How to write over image on specific position with HTML or PHP?

Tags: php, html, image

I am making a form in php and allow visitor to register for our site. Now after filling the form, I want to show his entries over a image at specific position. 
for example::

in this image:

[Contact form](http://previews.123rf.com/images/yupiramos/yupiramos1107/yupiramos110700237/10059368-papers-with-information-contact-name-e-mail-and-coment-over-blue-and-green-folders--Stock-Vector.jpg)
[image]

after inserting all the info in my site's contact form, I want to show details in above image; like name, email, comment.

So my question is, how can write text over image at specified position?

Comment: Create a Div First, set the background image to the the Contact Form image, then create different <span>'s for name email and comment. Manipulate the position of the span using CSS. Insert the correct data with the JS `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` on the container and 
make your form `position:relative`. Use Top, Right, Left, Bottom values to adjust it where ever you want.
Add the `background:url(imagepath);` to your form or inner div.